# How can I change default values of kivy widgets?

Tags: python, widget, kivy

Although it seems like a pretty task, I can not figure out, how to configure for example Widget.width.defaultvalue in kivy.

The widget I have in mind is defined as follows in the .kv file:

```
<Snake>:
    size: 20, 20
    canvas:
        Color:
            rgb: 1, 1, 1
        Rectangle:
            pos: self.pos
            size: self.size
```

This Snake Widget is in principal nothing but:

```
class Snake(Widget):
    pass
```

However, when I wanted to add such a Snake in my python code, trying to position it in the bottom right corner, I found out, that the width defaultvalue is 100 instead of the 20 I defined in the .kv file.

```
class SnakeGame(Widget):

def __init__(self):
    super().__init__()
    self.add_widget(Snake(pos=(self.width - Snake.width.defaultvalue, self.y)))
```

For my snake class, I tried

```
super.width.defaultvalue = 20
```

which led to an error. Could anybody give me a hint, where I can change this defaultvalue?

Best regards!

**EDIT:**
The actual answer to my question is almost stupid simple:

```
class Snake(Widget):
        width = NumericProperty(20)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Access Snake widget's width

### Python code

1. Instantiate Snake object, `snake = Snake()`
2. Set Snake object position, `snake.pos = self.width - snake.width, self.y`
3. Add print() function to verify snake's width and position, `print("width={0}, pos={1}".format(snake.width, snake.pos))`
4. Add snake widget/object to root widget.

### Snippet - Python code

```
class SnakeGame(FloatLayout):

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(SnakeGame, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        snake = Snake()
        snake.pos = self.width - snake.width, self.y
        print("width={0}, pos={1}".format(snake.width, snake.pos))
        self.add_widget(snake)
```

### kv file

1. Add `size_hint: None, None` to override widget's default `size: (100, 100)` or default `size_hint: (1, 1)`.

### Snippet - kv file

```
<Snake>:
    size_hint: None, None
    size: 20, 20
```

[Widget » default size](https://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.uix.widget.html)

> - The default size of a widget is (100, 100).
> - The default size_hint is (1, 1).

Please refer to the snippet and example for details.

## Snake - size_hint

Add `size_hint: None, None` to override widget's default `size: (100, 100)` or `size_hint: (1, 1)`.

```
<Snake>:
    size_hint: None, None
    size: 20, 20
```

[Widget » size_hint](https://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.uix.layout.html#understanding-the-size-hint-property-in-widget)

> If you don’t want to use a `size_hint` for either the width or height,
>   set the value to None.

## SnakeGame - pos_hint

1. Replace `Widget` with `FloatLayout`
2. Use `pos_hint={'right': 1}`

### Snippet

```
class SnakeGame(FloatLayout):

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(SnakeGame, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.add_widget(Snake(pos_hint={'right': 1}))
```

[Widget » pos_hint](https://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.uix.widget.html#kivy.uix.widget.Widget.pos_hint)

> ```
> pos_hint
> ```
>
> Position hint. This property allows you to set the position of the
>   widget inside its parent layout, in percent (similar to size_hint).
>
> For example, if you want to set the top of the widget to be at 90%
>   height of its parent layout, you can write:
>
> ```
> widget = Widget(pos_hint={'top': 0.9})
> ```
>
> The keys ‘x’, ‘right’ and ‘center_x’ will use the parent width. The
>   keys ‘y’, ‘top’ and ‘center_y’ will use the parent height.
>
> See [Float Layout](https://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.uix.floatlayout.html) for further reference.
>
> **Note**
>
> pos_hint is not used by all layouts. Check the documentation of the
>   layout in question to see if it supports pos_hint.
>
> pos_hint is an ObjectProperty containing a dict.

## Example

### main.py

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout


class Snake(Widget):
    pass


class SnakeGame(FloatLayout):

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(SnakeGame, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.add_widget(Snake(pos_hint={'right': 1}))


class TestApp(App):
    title = "Kivy - Snake Game"

    def build(self):
        return SnakeGame()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    TestApp().run()
```

### test.kv

```
#:kivy 1.11.0

<Snake>:
    size_hint: None, None
    size: 20, 20
    canvas:
        Color:
            rgb: 1, 1, 1
        Rectangle:
            pos: self.pos
            size: self.size
```

## Output

[image: Img01]

Comment: Wow, thank you for this beautiful answer! 
I have been struggeling for a while, whether to accept this answer or not as it does not tackle the actual answer (how/where to change the defaultvalue of properties). However, it solves the problem in my example most elegantly and actually also the one for my usecase. And again: That is such a well made answer! Therefore: Accept!
Thank you!